# Spark SQL selecting people that tweeted on at least 5 different days

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

first time using Spark SQL.
I have a DF with the following columns'tweet_date', 'user_screen_name', 'user_id_str'. my objective is to select all user_id_str and user_screen_names that tweeted on 5 different days (tweet_date).

My code currently looks like this but I believe it is wrong.

```
task12=spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT user_id_str, user_screen_name FROM  tweet2 WHERE (user_id_str)>=5")
```

When I replace

```
WHERE (user_id_str)>=5
#to
WHERE (tweet_date)>=5
```

my output df is blank

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can **`group by`** on user_screen_names..etc column and **`count(distinct(tweet_date))`** to get count of tweet_dates.

- filter the result using **`having`** clause.

---

**`Sample Query:`**

```
#this query results names where tweet_date count is atleast 5
spark.sql("select user_screen_name,count(distinct(tweet_date)) cnt from dd group by user_screen_name having cnt >= 5").show()
```